# Doctrine 2.0 integration into Zend Framework 1.10

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

can anybody help me how to nice integrate doctrine 2.0 into ZF 1.10? I found some application resources, but there was no complete solution. Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to setup it like described in this [blog post about ZF & Doctrine 2](http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/2009/11/doctrine-2-and-zend-framework.html).

Hope this suits your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot, but this link links to this thread, can you please paste working link? many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i litte late but there is new framework of frameworks for php. Its the zf-boilerplate, it contains, zf frame work 1.11.11, doctrine 2.1.2 and a lot of other nice bolt ons. Its fully integrated, google zf-boilerplate. Cheers

Answer (score -4):

You're going to find it very difficult (I was going to say no chance, but that's me being a pessimist) - ZF 1.10 is dependent on PHP 5.2, Doctrine 2.0 is written from the ground up for PHP 5.3.

You'd be better off either using Doctrine 1.2, which *is* working fine with ZF 1.10, or waiting for the upcoming ZF 2.0 release (which may be some time yet).

Comment: Zend Framework works on both PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3. Source code does not use namespaces and other PHP 5.3 features, but you may use them in your projects with ZF (e.g. ZF's autoloader should work fine with namespaces).

Comment: That might be true, but the original poster did not state that he was using PHP 5.3, and my understanding was thus that he was using PHP 5.2 and attempting to integrate something that would just never work. Can't help thinking the downvotes are a bit harsh in that respect.

Comment: Aren't we this kind who do read manuals, requirements first? Aren't we? Then who does when we do not?!

Comment: Fair point - I should really have asked for clarification of the user's setup before jumping off the deep end. I've upvoted your response anyway.